# Extract from a long string data based on certain words

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a bulk import into a database of pasted text.

Basically the data comes like following:

```
*******
First Name: First
Last Name: Last
Age:23
Browser:IE
*******

======
First Name- First
Last Name- Last
Age-23
Browser Type- IE
========
```

As you can see, both the separator characters(entries and titles "-" and ":" + "====" and "****" ) will be different as the titles(we have Browser in 1st and Browsert Type in 2nd).

There can be hundreds of rows with random format like this.
What I'm trying to achieve is pretty much just get the data past the separator character(either - or :) and assign that the first row equals to first name, second row equals to last name, etc. The rows and the order will always be the same is what I'm trying to explain.

Originally I was thinking of doing this with `explode("\n", $importData);` but I believe a multi-dimensional array would be more fit to do this in order to insert the data into the database.

Any idea on how should I approach this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why the data is in this format ?

Comment: Are the `*******`, `======` and empty lines included? If so, does the difference between stars or equal signs have any significance?

Comment: @executable not my question to ask. It's manual written data by some people but they always keep the same format about the rows.

Comment: @CBroe yes they are included, there is no significance other than it separates one entry from another

Comment: Well then you could explode at the line break first, loop over the stuff, and push the data into a temporary array. Once you encounter these boundary markers, push the collected temporary data into your final result array, clear the temp array, and continue …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm parsing the data for each line and check if you have `-` or `:` as separator

```
<?php
$data ="*******
First Name: First1
Last Name: Last1
Age:22
Browser:IE1
*******

======
First Name- First2
Last Name- Last2
Age-23
Browser Type- IE2
========";

$new_arr1 = array();
$new_arr2 = array();

foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $data) as $line){
    if (strpos($line, ':') !== false) {
        $new_data = explode(":", $line);
        if(isset($new_data[1])){
            $new_arr1[] = $new_data[1];
        }
    }
    if (strpos($line, '-') !== false) {
        $new_data = explode("-", $line);
        if(isset($new_data[1])){
            $new_arr2[] = $new_data[1];
        }
    }
} 

if(isset($new_arr1)){
    var_dump($new_arr1);
}

if(isset($new_arr2)){
    var_dump($new_arr2);
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c93c3e26c739f0574e92a4159530781786182d04